# Sharing variables that come from intent between onCreate and onCreateView method in order to settext TextView

Tags: android, variables, global-variables, settext

```
package com.example.fizyka;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Wyniki extends ActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wyniki);
        Intent odbior = getIntent();
        Double Ua_wynik = odbior.getDoubleExtra(Ekran.NIEPEWNOSC,0);
        String Ua_ww = Double.toString(Ua_wynik);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.wyniki, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wyniki,
                    container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wyniki_finalne);
            textView.setText(Ua_ww);


            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

`textView.setText(Ua_ww);` in `onCreateView` method doesn't want to take `onCreate`'s `Ua_ww` variable. Eclipse says `Ua_ww cannot be resolved to a variable`. How to do it? That's how variable comes up to this activity, but I think that it doesn't matter:

```
package com.example.fizyka;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.fizyka.R;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Ekran extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String DANE_X = "Fizyka.DANE_WEJSCIE";
    public final static String EPSILON = "Fizyka.EPSILON";
    public final static String EPSILON_POTEGI = "Fizyka.EPSILON_POTEGI";
    public final static String SREDNIA = "Fizyka.SREDNIA";
    public final static String NIEPEWNOSC = "Fizyka.NIEPEWNOSC";
    public final static String EPSILON_POTEGI_SUMA = "Fizyka.EPSILON_POTEGI_SUMA";

public void srednia (View view){
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wynik);

    EditText wejscie = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wejscie);
     String dane_wejscie = wejscie.getText().toString();
     String arr[] = dane_wejscie.split("\\r?\\n");
     List<Double> dane = new ArrayList<Double>();
     for(int i = 0; i < arr.length;i++){
         dane.add(Double.parseDouble(arr[i].trim().replaceAll(",", ".")));}

     //Licze srednia
     Double srednia = 0.0;
     for(int i = 0; i < dane.size();i++){
         srednia = srednia + dane.get(i);}
     srednia = srednia / arr.length;
     textView.setText(String.valueOf(srednia));
     //Odejmuje średnią od danych
     Double[] roznice = new Double[arr.length];
     for(int i = 0;i < dane.size();i++){
         roznice[i]=dane.get(i)-srednia;
     }

     //Kwadraty roznic i ich suma
     Double[] roznice_sq = new Double[arr.length];
     Double suma_roznice_sq =0.0;
     for(int i = 0;i < dane.size();i++){
         roznice_sq[i]=Math.pow(roznice[i],2);
     }
     for(int i = 0;i < dane.size();i++){
         suma_roznice_sq=suma_roznice_sq+roznice_sq[i];
     }

     //Niepewność typu A
     double Ua=Math.sqrt((suma_roznice_sq/(arr.length*(arr.length-2))));
     //Przygotowanie do wysyłki
    Intent wysylka = new Intent(this,Wyniki.class);
    wysylka.putExtra(DANE_X, dane_wejscie);
    wysylka.putExtra(EPSILON, Arrays.toString(roznice));
    wysylka.putExtra(EPSILON_POTEGI, Arrays.toString(roznice_sq));
    wysylka.putExtra(SREDNIA, srednia);
    wysylka.putExtra(EPSILON_POTEGI_SUMA, suma_roznice_sq);
    wysylka.putExtra(NIEPEWNOSC, Ua);
    startActivity(wysylka);
}


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ekran);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ekran, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ekran,
                    container, false);


            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this

```
public class Wyniki extends ActionBarActivity {
    public String Ua_ww;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Your onCreate method, just change String Ua_ww = Double.toString(Ua_wynik);
        // to Ua_ww = Double.toString(Ua_wynik);
    }
```

Then in onCreateView do

```
textView.setText(((Wyniki)getActivity()).Ua_ww);
```

Answer (score 0):

the same way you would do it in an intent pretty much, you create a bundle and put what you want the fragment to get in there

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("some_key",Ua_ww);

FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment f = new PlaceholderFragment();
f.addArguments(b);
ft.add(R.id.container,f).commit();
```

then in your fragment call `getArguments()` to get the bundle and pull the key from the bundle to get the item you want